# JavaScript Getting Minutes Until 1st Of Next month

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the remaining minutes until the first of the following month.  So if it were February 27th at 00:00:01, I want to calculate the remaining minutes until it is February 28th.

I have been able to do this for minutes until next hour with `new Date().getMinutes()` and minutes until midnight with

```
function minsToMidnight() {
  var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date(now);
  then.setHours(24,0,0,0);
  return (then - now)/6e4;
}
```

Can't figure out how to extend to minutes to next month?

Comment: Quick note, `then` is not (currently) a reserved word in JavaScript, but it's still too generic to be safely used.

Comment: Perhaps `midnight` would be more appropriate.  It works as-is but I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function minsToMidnight(){

    var rightNow = new Date();
    var month = rightNow.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = rightNow.getFullYear();

    //If its a new year
    if (month > 12){
        month -= 12;
        year += 1;
    }

    var firstOfNextMonth = new Date(year, month, 01);

    return  (firstOfNextMonth - rightNow)/6e4;
}
```